# My scripts won't load in, is this code correct?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Here is my functions.php

```
    <?php 
 function my_custom_theme_styles() {
    // Enqueue your custom stylesheet named "style.css"
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_theme_styles'); 


function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . 'custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );

?>
```

And here is my footer.php

```
<div class="container">
    <p>&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Your Site Name. All rights reserved.</p>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><p>hi</p></li>
            <!-- Additional footer menu items can be added here -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked your browsers dev tools console for errors? Note that get_template_directory_uri doesn't return a trailing slash on the end

Answer (score 0):

The following functions print enqueued assets:

- [`wp_print_head_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_print_head_scripts/)
- [`wp_print_styles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_print_styles/)
- [`print_late_styles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/print_late_styles/)
- [`print_footer_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/print_footer_scripts/)

These functions are called on the [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) and [`wp_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/) actions. If your header and footer are not using the appropriate functions or actions, then the enqueued assets will not be printed.